# can't reorder geom_ribbon levels R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I keep running into this problem and can't figure out how to solve it. I use `geom_ribbon` to create a 95% CI band when I plot my data; however, when I reorder levels to change the order of my plots in a facet, my labels and data move, but my `geom_ribbon` does not. Here's a picture:

[image]

```
DiffDFCollapsed$Condition<-factor(DiffDFCollapsed$Condition, levels=c("No Response - Bimanual","Unimanual - Bimanual","No Response - Unimanual"))
DiffDFAll$Condition<-factor(DiffDFAll$Condition, levels=c("No Response - Bimanual","Unimanual - Bimanual","No Response - Unimanual"))

p1<-print(ggplot(DiffDFCollapsed, aes(Time, MUERD,group=Condition,colour=Condition)) +
    geom_line(size=1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(12,37,62,88,113,138,163,189),labels=c("-1000", "0", "1000","2000","3000","4000","5000","6000")) +

    geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
    geom_ribbon(aes(group=Condition,ymin=DiffDFCollapsed$CI_Low, ymax=DiffDFCollapsed$CI_High), linetype=2,alpha=0.3) +
    facet_wrap(~Condition,ncol=3)+
    ylab("Theta-Evenet Related Power (log transformed)")+
    xlab("TIME (in ms)")+
    theme(text=element_text(size=8),panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA),legend.position="none"))
```

I can add the data file if you need it, but I assume that I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

gah!!! Wouldn't you know it? As soon as I take the time to post a question, I figure it out. I needed to change this:

```
geom_ribbon(aes(group=Condition,ymin=DiffDFCollapsed$CI_Low, ymax=DiffDFCollapsed$CI_High), linetype=2,alpha=0.3) +
```

to this:

```
geom_ribbon(data=DiffDFCollapsed,aes(ymin=CI_Low, ymax=CI_High), linetype=2,alpha=0.3)
```